# Array search in mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, implode

There's a DB where I stored the products details. (id, name, price, category, unit)

Firstly i'm listed the products for select in a php file named 'input.php'. It works like a charm.

```
// SQL query

    $query = "SELECT    * 
              FROM      products
              ORDER BY  p_name
              ASC";

            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if($result === FALSE) {die(mysql_error());}?>

                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td width="800px"><h1>Product name</h1></td>
                        <td width="400px"><h1>Product price</h1></td>
                        <td>Category</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="pro_name[]" value="<?=$row['p_name']?>"></td>
                        <td width="800px" align="left"><b><?=$row['p_name']?></b></td>
                        <td width="400px" align="left"><?=$row['p_price']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?=$row['p_cat']?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?}
```

I submit the data to 'index.php' and handle the variables in there.

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST"){

// Variables

$c_name = $_POST['c_name'];             //  ['company name']
$c_consumption = $_POST['c_consumption'];   //  ['company consumptions']
$f_price = $_POST['f_price'];               //  ['fuel price']
$o_sales = $_POST['o_sales'];               //  ['sales']
$pro_name = $_POST['pro_name'];         //  ['products names']
$pro_id = $_POST['pro_id'];             //  ['product id']  
$pro_price = $_POST['pro_price'];           //  ['product price']
```

The third step where i'm stucked...I need to list the picked products details.

My idea is to select the details from the db with search for the product names what i picked earlier.

I tried it with IN, LIKE, implode....etc but it didn't work. :(

```
// SQL query

      $query = "SELECT  * 
                      FROM      products
                      WHERE     p_name IN (".implode(',', $pro_name).")
                      ORDER BY  p_name
                      ASC";

            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if($result === FALSE) {die(mysql_error());}

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                <table>
                    <tr>                            
                        <td width="800px" align="left"><b><?=$row['p_name']?></b></td>
                        <td width="400px" align="left"><?=$row['p_price']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?=$row['p_cat']?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?}
                }
```

EDIT:

```
 var_dump($pro_name); result

 array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "12 V szivattyú" [1]=> string(17) "120 l/p szivattyú" [2]=> string(28) "24 hónapra bővített garancia" }
```

Comment: What error messages or output are you getting?

Comment: if `p_name` is VARCHAR then `IN` statement should have `'`: `IN ('p_name_1', 'p_name_2')`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'V szivattyú,120 l/p szivattyú,24 hónapra bővített garancia) ' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

What is the $pro_name value ?
If you are using implode then should be an array like $pro_name=array('Fruit','Chocolate','Mirror');
Then query would be:

```
SELECT  * 
                      FROM      products
                     -> WHERE     p_name IN ("Fruit,Chocolate,Mirror")
                      ORDER BY  p_name
                      ASC
```

But the problem is that the query is still wrong, because of ", then u should remove and change to

```
WHERE     p_name IN (implode(',', $pro_name))
```

Then query will be like

```
SELECT  * 
                          FROM      products
                         -> WHERE     p_name IN (Fruit,Chocolate,Mirror)
                          ORDER BY  p_name
                          ASC
```

Comment: var_dump($pro_name);



array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "12 V szivattyú" [1]=> string(17) "120 l/p szivattyú" [2]=> string(28) "24 hónapra bővített garancia" }

Answer (score 0):

If the p_name is a string type, I'm pretty sure the $pro_names that you are imploding need to be delimited with ' (single quote delimiter). It looks like what you have in your script would be interpreted by the sql parser as column names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
var_dump(implode("','",$pro_name));
                      result:                                                   
string(65) "12 V szivattyú','120 l/p szivattyú','24 hónapra bővített garancia" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'V szivattyú,120 l/p szivattyú,24 hónapra bővített garancia) ORDER BY p_' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL

```
 $pr_name = ltrim(implode(',' , '".$pro_name."'), ',');  
 $query = "SELECT  * 
           FROM products
           WHERE p_name IN ($pr_name)
           ORDER BY p_name
           ASC";
```

Comment: Thanks fo your answer. I tried it:  

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\AppServ\www\projekt\hardver\index.php on line 49
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY p_name ASC' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Help me a lot to solve the problem.

Here's my solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pro_id[]" value="<?=$row['p_id']?>">
```

It creates an array:

```
string(24) "6, 7, 10, 20, 21, 49, 54"
```

Than

```
$list = implode(', ', $pro_id);
```

SQL

```
// SQL query
$query = " SELECT      * 
           FROM       products
           WHERE      p_id IN ($list)
           ORDER BY   p_name
           ASC ";
```

I think the names contains characters what the query can't handle so now the query based on ID. I don't know why i'm not work with id at the begin... my bad.